# How to open a Flutter Android studio project in xCode?

Tags: xcode, flutter

I've developed an application with Flutter with Android Studio. Now I want to build the app for iOS. I installed xCode on my Mac and git cloned the repository from github in xCode. How could I open the project in xCode? If I try to open the folder i get "Unable to open the file".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Xcode You can open ios specific part of the project which is located in `ios/xcworkspace`.

Answer (score 0):

To open a Flutter project in Xcode, you first need to make sure that you have built the correct Flutter files for `ios`, so, first, run:

```
flutter build ios
```

And then open your file under the directory `ios/MYPROJECT.xcworkspace`